# How to override navbar over the background image?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I try to place a basic bootstrap navbar over the background image, but it only shows the part of the navbar in the corner. I want to have the whole navbar at the top. I know that I should override something, but what?

I tried to make use of `!important`, but it only changes the color of the part, not the whole navbar.
[image: my website page]

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Who am I?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark bg-custom">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Icon-round-Question_mark.svg/600px-Icon-round-Question_mark.svg.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="question mark">
                Who am I?
              </a>
            </nav>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

css:

`

```
body{
    background-image: url(https://besthqwallpapers.com/Uploads/5-12-2018/73473/wooden-background-brown-tree-brown-background-wooden-pattern-vertical-lines.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}


.navbar{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #916E34, #915D34, #914C34) !important;
}
```

`

So what should I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.
Add this code in you css `header{width:100%;}`.

```css
body{
    background-image: url(https://besthqwallpapers.com/Uploads/5-12-2018/73473/wooden-background-brown-tree-brown-background-wooden-pattern-vertical-lines.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

header{
  width:100%;
}
.navbar{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #916E34, #915D34, #914C34) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Who am I?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark bg-custom">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Icon-round-Question_mark.svg/600px-Icon-round-Question_mark.svg.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="question mark">
                Who am I?
              </a>
            </nav>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for help!Confused me a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
    background-image: url(https://besthqwallpapers.com/Uploads/5-12-2018/73473/wooden-background-brown-tree-brown-background-wooden-pattern-vertical-lines.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navbar{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #916E34, #915D34, #914C34) !important;
     width:100vw;
}
```

That should work

[Working Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/cm30yu2v/)

Comment: Thanks for help!A newbie,so got stuck at this quite obvious moment :).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `display: flex;`. It's making your navbar to flex.